# How to add QuotePrefix in Apache poi version 4.0.1 hssf

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssf

I'm using Apache POI version 4.0.1. I want to set `setQuotePrefixed(true)` for my cell style. But I couldn't find this method in Hssf workbook cellstyle. Is there a way to do this?

```
CellStyle style = setStyle(workbook, font);

private CellStyle setStyle(XSSFWorkbook workbook, Font font) {
    XSSFCellStyle wrapBorderedCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    wrapBorderedCellStyle.getCoreXf().setQuotePrefix(true);
    wrapBorderedCellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    wrapBorderedCellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    wrapBorderedCellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_TOP);
    wrapBorderedCellStyle.setFont(font);
    wrapBorderedCellStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    wrapBorderedCellStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    wrapBorderedCellStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    return wrapBorderedCellStyle;
}

setUpTextCell(style, row, 9, record.getInvoiceNumber().replace(" ", "'"));
```

Comment: The `HSSFCellStyle` of `apache poi 4.0.1` has that method . See https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.java?view=markup#l258. So not clear where your problem is. Please check that there are no jars from lower `apache poi` versions in class path. Mixing different `apache poi` versions is not supported. See https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204.

Comment: XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();

style.getCoreXf().setQuotePrefix(true);
is this the one you referring to?

Comment: For both, `HSSF` and `XSSF`: `CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle(); style.setQuotePrefixed(true);` . See: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setQuotePrefixed-boolean-`.

Comment: Or for `HSSF` only: `HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle(); style.setQuotePrefixed(true);`. See: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setQuotePrefixed-boolean-. Or for `XSSF` only: `XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle(); style.setQuotePrefixed(true);`. See: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setQuotePrefixed-boolean-.

Comment: For `XSSFWorkbook` its not getting resolved. This is the one getting resolved ` style.getCoreXf().setQuotePrefix(true);`

Comment: @AxelRichter updated the question with the implementation. Please check

Comment: Even though i did this with this way, the expected outcome doesn't come. `'2019671045191` i want to remove this appended `'` when its shown in the excel